# Why am I not seeing console.log output in my Netlify function logs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, scheduled-tasks, netlify

I have a Netlify function that is scheduled to run every minute using the schedule method from the @netlify/functions package. The function makes API calls and logs the response using console.log("response: ", response.data);. However, I'm not seeing any output from this console.log statement in the Netlify function logs.

Here's the code for my function:

```js
import { Handler, HandlerEvent, HandlerContext, schedule } from "@netlify/functions";
import { dbIndex } from "src/app/dbIndex";
import { RestAPIService } from "src/service/RestAPI.service";

const getData: Handler = async (event: HandlerEvent, context: HandlerContext) => {
  console.log("Received event:", event);

  try {
    const responses = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dbIndex.length; i++) {

      const response = await RestAPIService.fetchTransactions({
        id: dbIndex[i].id,
        merch: dbIndex[i].merch,
        date: dbIndex[i].date,
      });
      console.log("response->>>: ", response.data);
      responses.push(response.data);
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return {
        statusCode: 500,
        message: e
    }
  }
};

const handler = schedule("* * * * *", getData)

export { handler };
```

I only can see `console.log("Received event:", event);` after I try to run this function locally everything works fine, I can see logs.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Checking that the function is deployed and running on Netlify
2. Verifying that the featuredTokens array is correctly importing
   values
3. Modifying the console.log statement to see if any output appears
   Checking the function execution logs for error messages

None of these steps have solved the issue. What could be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it possible you are not receiving a response from `RestAPIService.fetchTransactions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your function throwing an exception. Try to add a console.log on a catch like that:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  console.log({ e });
  return {
    statusCode: 500,
    message: e
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, but I have tested to manually trigger this function  on localhost but it works, I'll test prod deployment now